# How to set ASP.net MVC Grid Column text length?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to set MVC Grid Column Text length.

like en example. if Text is :

`" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus nulla eu dolor. Nulla porta bibendum lectus quis euismod. Aliquam volutpat ultricies porttitor. Cras risus nisi, accumsan vel cursus ut, sollicitudin vitae dolor. Fusce scelerisque eleifend lectus in bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia egestas felis a volutpat. "`

Then Grid Column Shows it like this : " **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...** "

I tried it with Substring but it gives error.
like this

> grid.Column("TicketDescription".Substring(0,30)+'....', header: "Description", style: "charlength")

Any Suggestion on this
help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the 'text-overflow: ellipsis;' css styling:

add the next style to your cell

```
 .trimmed -text{
    height: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```